# Analyzing RDF Graph: average number of certain relation

Tags: graph, rdf, sparql

I'm new to SPARQL.

I'm trying to find a way to generally analyze and RDF graph, meaning for example the average number of a certain relation for a subject.
So if we would have the data

```
[Alice         likes     Money]
[Bob           has       Money]
[Bob           likes     Diving] 
[Bob           likes     Skiing]
```

What is the average number of "likes" per node, (here: 1.5).

My first try is to simply write a script to iterate all distinct objects and query for the count of likes relations on each.

Is there a way to do this directly in SPARQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use `GROUP BY` and aggregates for this kind of thing.  See [Aggregates](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates) in the specification for an overview of this.

If you wanted to get the likes per node you can do so like so:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/ns#>

SELECT ?node (COUNT(*) AS ?likes)
WHERE
{
  ?s :likes ?node
}
GROUP BY ?node
```

Here we group by the `?node` and do a `COUNT(*)` which simply counts the number of solutions in the group.  This gives us the number of likes for every distinct `?node` value in a single query.

If we wanted to find the average likes per node we can also do this using aggregates:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/ns#>

SELECT 
 (COUNT(*) AS ?likeCount) 
 (COUNT(DISTINCT ?node) AS ?nodeCount) 
 (?likeCount / ?nodeCount AS ?avgLikesPerNode)
WHERE
{
  ?s :likes ?node .
}
```

Here we use `COUNT(*)` again to get the total number of likes and then we use `COUNT(DISTINCT ?node)` which will count the distinct values for `?node` and then we can simply divide our `?likeCount` by our `?nodeCount` to give us the average likes per node.